# nginx show for spefici user a html page

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to show for certrain countries a page that the service is not available it need to be showed whatever URL they access, how I can do this?

Means user type: domain.com/whatever we will show all the time content from a static page unavailable.html or forward to them. The static content file is in another root.

```
if ($allow_visit = no) {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /unavailable.html last;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about [nginx Geo module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGeoModule). Documentation also contains the link on how to create your own MaxMind based config file.